# Differentiating an integral with an indicator function

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I have the following integral

$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} f(x) \textbf{1}\{x^Tv \geq c\} dx$$
where $v$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I would like to differentiate this with respect to $c$ (we can assume $f$ has as many derivatives as we want, if it helps). My thought was that we can write the difference quotient as
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}  \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \int_c^{c + \epsilon} f(x) \textbf{1}\{x^Tv = y \}dydx$$
But now I'm a bit stumped. If this is differentiable in $c$, the derivative should look something like
$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} f(x) \textbf{1}\{x^Tv = c \} dx$$
but the set $\{x \text{ : } x^Tv = c \}$ is measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^d$, so this integral would be zero. Should I be getting an integral with respect to some $(d - 1)$-dimensional measure or something? Or is this not the right approach more generallty?